# Django deployment variables

Tags: django

I have a development app running locally. I have a production app running on my server. I would like to keep developing locally and push my changes. However, the dev version uses local postgres and the static and media files reside inside the project. The server version the static and media files are in a static public_html directory served by apache. Can I have a local static and media files as well as different postgres credentials on localhost than on the server? How do I accomplish that?

Comment: How are you providing the credentials currently, are they hardcoded into the `settings.py` file?

Comment: No, I’m reading from a json file outside of the project

Comment: I might not be following this so forgive me. I'm assuming you are developing locally and pushing changes to a server. Is it possible to update the credentials (and other related information) in the json file. That way you have local development credentials in one version of the JSON settings file and production credentials in another?

Comment: I guess that would work for credentials. What about the directories? Should I create variables in the json for those as well? I wasn’t sure if I could just put folders inside of the project, then on prod use symlinks.

Comment: Yeah that is what I do. The only difference is that I use .env files for what you are describing. Which just closely follows the 12 factor app principal. I'll write out an answer with a bit more detail but you are asking the right questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [python-dotenv](https://pypi.org/project/python-dotenv/) package is designed specifically for the issue you are running into. Instead of using JSON files it uses `.env` files which follows the practice of [12 factor apps](https://12factor.net/).

An example would be

**settings.py**

```py
from dotenv import load_dotenv
load_dotenv()

DEBUG = os.getenv('DEBUG', 1)  # with a default value
SECRET_KEY = os.getenv('DJANGO_SECRET_KEY')

DB_USERNAME = os.getenv('DB_USERNAME')
DB_PASSWORD = os.getenv('DB_PASSWORD')

LOGGING_FOLDER = os.getenv('LOGGING_FOLDER')

# Allowed hosts can be stored and split into a list
# Also the name in the separate settings file does not have to match the settings.py variable name
ALLOWED_HOSTS = os.getenv('HOSTS', '').split(' ')
# This will be ['locahost', 'localhost:8000']

# ...
```

**.env**

```
DJANGO_SECRET_KEY=somethingotherthanthis
DB_USERNAME=postgres
DB_PASSWORD=123456
LOGGING_FOLDER=/var/logging/app/
HOSTS=localhost localhost:8000
```

Of course you don't have to use the external package you can always use the JSON file and only change the following code in your settings. What you will want to be careful of in both circumstances is that the file you are saving your sensitive data and environment specific information (like media folders, logging folders, etc) is not checked into the version control system.

**settings.py**

```py
import json
with open('settings.json') as fh:
    file_settings = json.load(fh)

DEBUG = file_settings.get('DEBUG', 1)

# ...
```

Comment: would you mind sharing how you do symlinks for deployment? I would like to keep MEDIA_ROOT = '/static' but on my server I am serving media from apache static site. MEDIA_ROOT = '/var/www/html/media.bradrice.com/public_html/'. If I try ln -s /var/www/html/media.bradrice.com/public_html media it doesn't seem to create the link the right way.

Comment: That’s a good question, that I don’t have an answer for lol. I’d suggest creating a separate question